# Jar file is not executed when used in shell script in a crontab?

Tags: shell, unix, jar, cron

Below is my shell-script located in /app/Scripts.

Test.sh :

```
#!/bin/sh
usr/bin/java -jar /app/Scripts/emailJAR.jar >> /app/pvs/test.txt
echo $(date) >> /app/Scripts/test.txt
```

I have scheduled cron-tab as `* * * * * /app/Scripts/Test.sh`

I am getting the output of "echo $(date)" every minute, but, not usr/bin/java -jar /app/Scripts/emailJAR.jar.

Can anybody have any advice ?

Script location,Jar location, executable permission all are set. Still only the java -jar command executed thru crontab.

Mystery, I am able to run the script manually.

Please help me on this issue .

Answer (score 0):

```
>> /app/pvs/test.txt
```

Looks like it may be taken as arguments into the .jar file, like so:

```
java -jar myJar.jar arg1 arg2 arg3 etc
```

You can do

```
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(args));
```

In your programs main method, to test whether or not my statement is true.

Or the output you are looking for is being redirected to the out-stream of the test.txt file you reference

I hope you tested the jar works prior to trying to place it in the crontab, as well as the command itself.

Answer (score 0):

In the second line, try changing `usr/bin/java` to `/usr/bin/java`. As currently written, it only works when executed from the root directory, and crontab is probably executing from some other directory.